# In Magento is it possible to duplicate a table rates shipping method?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

In Magento 2 is it possible to duplicate a table rates shipping method?
The store needs one for international shipping where the shipping price depends on  number of items.
And an other one for domestic shipping where the shipping price depends on subtotal.